# Email dispatch: SmtpCmdResp: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied

Tags: exm

**Sitecore**: 9.0.2 XP0 Standlaone

**Issue**: Unable to send emails as a regular campaign

**Log in EDS**:

```
SmtpCmdResp: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.
```

**Log in EXM**:

```
ERROR Message sending error:System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.EDS.Core.Exceptions.InvalidMessageException: Failed to send the email message due to incorrect data.
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatTransportClient.SendAsync(Email message)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<RetryOnFault>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<SendTaskAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider.<SendEmailAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchProviderBase.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.SendEmail.SendEmail.Process(SendMessageArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.PipelineHelper.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.TestMessageTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Sitecore.EDS.Core.Exceptions.InvalidMessageException: Failed to send the email message due to incorrect data.
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatTransportClient.SendAsync(Email message)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<RetryOnFault>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<SendTaskAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider.<SendEmailAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchProviderBase.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()<---
```

**Changes in config**:
 Only  4 fields were updated

1. Server
2. Port
3. Username
4. Password

**What I have tried**:
I changed the above 4 details from my organisation to different Outlook email-id of another organisation. But the logs are same.

What could be the cause?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Have you updated startTls to "true" and authenticationMethod to "LOGIN"?

Comment: @SwatiGupta: In the previous set of login details. when it was working, there was no password. So, I had not set the authentication mode to login. I am not using TLS so I have provided the port number accordingly. In the Outlook set of data, I had provided 'Authentication mode' to Login, even though the log is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have faced the same issue on EXM. The reason was `from` address was not a valid one. It wasn't authorized.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction.  If an idiot like me comes here, 'please check the final values in showconfig'. You don't know who is over-riding where.